# Where is the editor language configured in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, syntax-highlighting

I am editing files for FsYacc and FsLex in Visual Studio 2010 Shell. These files have an extension of fsl and fsx, and there is no editing support like syntax highlightning or IntelliSense, and the comment/uncomment buttons are disabled.

Where can I configure Visual Studio to use the F# settings for fsl and fsx files? These would not be optimal, but much better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're up for registry hacking, I note e.g.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config\Languages\File Extensions\.fs
```

in a VS2010 Professional install, you can probably copy the key/value with .fsl instead maybe.

Comment: This works but you need to shutdown all instances of visual studio before the syntax highlighting takes effect.

Answer (score 1):

tools -> options

then expand 'text editor' -> file extension

you can associate particular editors to be associated with particular file types.

Comment: The answer is probably correct, but the Visual Studio Shell edition does not seem to allow to select F# here.

Comment: hrmm, i just noticed that too. i'm not sure which editor F# uses by default... you might have to try picking a couple of the different script editor options and see if one works for you.